# Magento2 : update query though upgradeData script

Tags: magento2, upgradeschema

I want to update data to particular value in database. How to write script for the below query

```
    update tablename set name="Test" where id="4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update increment version in module.xml like setup_version="1.0.1", make sure in db setup_module table data should be 1.0.0
and add below code in upgradeData.php

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;


class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "1.0.1", "<")) {
              $table = $setup->getTable('test');
              $setup->getConnection()->update($table, ['name' => 'test123'], 'id IN (1)');
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a file e.g `root_magento_dir/pub/example_file.php`.
Paste this code in your file.

```
<?php
include(__DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php');

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;


$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_CRONTAB);

$resourceConnection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resourceConnection->getConnection();
$connection->query('update tablename set name="Test" where id="4"');

die("Done");
```

Run this file via URL `https://www.example.com/example_file.php`
Or you can run it directly via Shell `cd path/to/pub/directory && php example_file.php`.

Thank you.

Comment: You can remove that die if you want, It's just a script therefore it doesn't matter if we kill it at the end. I've used that die just to indicate that script has done it's work

Comment: But don't forget to delete this script after your work is done because this could be accessed via URL and it makes our site vulnerable for hackers.

Comment: yes so that i need this script through upgradeData

Comment: can u plz provide solution with upgradedata.php